# Bad tag wiki review about to be approved

Tags: discussion, review, tag-wiki

I just rejected this tag wiki [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1381605), but see that two others have approved it.  My problem with it was that it used too much first person in it, and it had donation asking text in it.  I imagine he just cut and pasted a web page into it.

Any opinions?

Comment: Straight copy from the https://github.com/TideSDK/TideSDK github page. Plagiarism should be declined indeed.

Comment: He sounds like he might be one of the guys on the project so it wouldn't be plagiarism (yep, same name 'fairwinds').

Comment: Ah, indeed. But where is the attribution then?

Comment: @LanceRoberts: According to his About Me section, he is. Anyways, that wiki reads like an advertisement. It's disgusting.

Comment: Should be rolled back, it's been approved.

Comment: Dangit, now it got approved, and it'll take some edit work to clean it up.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, yeh, I don't have tag wiki rollback privileges on SO.

Comment: OK, I edited it, but don't know how to link the review for it (probably don't see the link because I can only make suggested tag wiki edits on SO).

Comment: @LanceRoberts: You can go into your profile - activity - suggestions, and the "suggested edit" part before "on *x* tag wiki" will be a link to the suggestion.

Comment: OK, voting to close as too localized now.